# How can I prove that $\{tx+y: t\in \Bbb{R}, ~y\in Y\}$ is closed in $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

> Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of a real normed space $X$ and pick $x\in X\setminus Y$. Then define $$Z:=\{tx+y: t\in \Bbb{R}, ~y\in Y\}$$I want to show that $Z$ is closed in $X$

I would have done it as follows:

Let $(z_n)_n$ be a convergent sequence in $Z$, i.e. $z_n=t_nx+y_n$, and assume $z_n\rightarrow z$ in $X$. we need to show that $z\in Z$.
Since $(z_n)$ converges, also $(t_n)$ and $(y_n)$ converges. To be more precisely $t_n\rightarrow t$ in $\Bbb{R}$. Furthermore $y_n\rightarrow y$ in $X$ but since $Y$ is closed $y\in Y$ therefore since $Z$ is a subspace $z_n=t_nx+y_n\rightarrow tx+y$ where $x\in X\setminus Y$ and $y\in Y$ thus $\lim_n z_n=z\in Z$.

Does this work or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It would be $t_{n}x$ instead of $tx_{n}$, since $x$ is fixed

Comment: @RaulFernandesHorta I edited it now, would it now work?

Comment: For me it is not so clear how convergence of $z_{n}$ implies convergence of $t_{n}$ and $y_{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** To prove that $Z$ is closed you need to show that if there is a sequence $z_{n}\in Z$ which converges to some $x\in X$ then $x\in Z$. That's what closedness means. So you cannot make a statement like "convergent sequence in $Z$". You are taking a sequence which is convergent in $X$ and showing that the limit is in $Z$ and hence $Z$ is closed.

**Solution**:

You have $d(x,Y)>0$

We claim that $|t|d(x,Y)\leq ||tx+y||$ for all $t$.

If $t=0$ then the inequality is trivially true.

If $t\neq 0$ then

$d(x,Y)=\inf_{y\in Y} ||x+y|| =\inf_{y\in Y} ||x+\frac{1}{t}y||=\frac{1}{|t|}\inf_{y\in Y}||tx+y||\leq\frac{1}{|t|} ||tx+y||$ for any fixed $y\in Y$.

So $||tx+y||\geq |t|d(x,Y) $ .

So now consider a sequence $z_{n}=t_{n}x+y_{n}$ that converges in $X$.

Then  $|t_{n}|\leq \frac{1}{d(x,Y)}||t_{n}x+y_{n}||$ . But $t_{n}x+y_{n}$ converges and hence $||t_{n}x+y_{n}||$ is bounded. So we have by Bolzano Weirestrass theorem that we get a convergent subsequence $t_{n_{k}}$ such that $t_{n_{k}}\to t$ say.

Then as $t_{n_{k}}x+y_{n_{k}}$ converges(subsequence of convergent sequence) and $t_{n_{k}}$ converges, we have $y_{n_{k}}$ converges to some $y$ say. This $y$ must be in $Y$ as $Y$ is closed.

Then $t_{n_{k}}x+y_{n_{k}}$ converges to $tx+y\in Z$ . But since the sequence $t_{n}x+y_{n}$ itself converges, it must do so to the unique limit $tx+y$.

**Alternatively** $\frac{1}{d(x,Y)}|(t_{n}-t_{m})x+(y_{n}-y_{m})|\geq |t_{n}-t_{m}|$ so $z_{n}$ is Cauchy implies $t_{n}$ is Cauchy which means $t_{n}$ is convergent . Thus $y_{n}$ is convergent and hence you get the result the same way as we did above.

Hence $Z$ is closed.

Just take a note that by above, you have proved that the sum of a closed subspace and a finite dimensional subspace is always closed.

Comment: ah okey. But why can't I only work with $t_{n_k}x+y_n$, so why do I need $y_{n_k}$?

Comment: Is $t_{n_{k}}+y_{n}$ a subsequence of $z_{n}$ ?

Comment: No it isn't but the problem is I don't really see why we need a subsequence

Comment: Well you only need it because I proved it that way. Otherwise by using the inequality I gave you can directly show that $t_{n}$ is cauchy. In that case you don't need subsequences. I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is wrong. "Since $(z_n)$ converges, also $(t_n)$ and $(y_n)$ converges"?? This is a huge step and you have to prove this.

Consider two cases:

Case 1:  $(t_n)$ is bounded. In this case some subsequence $t_{n_k}$ converges to some $t$. Since $t_{n_k}x+y_{n_k}$ also converges we see that $y_{n_k}$ converges to some $y$ which must be in $Y$. Hence, $z=tx+y$

Case 2. $(t_n)$ is unbounded. In this case some subsequence $t_{n_k}$ tends to $\infty$ and we can take limits in $z_{n_k}/t_{n_k}=x+y_{n_k}/t_{n_k}$ to see that $-y_{n_k}/t_{n_k} (\in Y) \to x$ contradicting the fact that $Y$ is closed and $x \notin Y$.